# How does the maximum number of guesses needed to win Mastermind (board game) change as the size of the board increases?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

Donald Knuth demonstrated that the codebreaker in the board game [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)) can solve the pattern in five moves or fewer using the following algorithm:

> 1. Create a set S of remaining possibilities (at this point there are 1296). The first guess is aabb.
> 2. Remove all possibilities from S that would not give the same score of colored and white pegs if they were the answer.
> 3. For each possible guess (not necessarily in S) calculate how many possibilities from S would be eliminated for each possible colored/white score. The score of the guess is the least of such values. Play the guess with the highest score (minimax).
> 4. Go back to step 2 until you have got it right.

I am curious: what would be the maximum number of guesses necessary to win a Mastermind-like game with 5 pegs instead of 4? How about 1,000 pegs, or a million?

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.04597.pdf) surveys many relevant results.